# SSAS cube MDX LIKE

Tags: ssas, mdx

using this script in ssas cube:

```
([Account].[Syntetic account].&[P]&[602],[Measures].[Amount])
```

I am able to select all amounts related to syntetic account number 602.

Right now I'm not able to select all amounts for accounts beginning on 6 (use something similar to "LIKE '6%'.
Is there any option for that? Thank you for your help

Ondra

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use a filter (or except) on the hierarchy as explained https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/59fb7777-2360-4be1-95ac-63a3d00ff4b3/filter-out-a-specific-member-of-a-dimension-hierarchy-in-mdx-query.